# Möbius Transformation from a disk into a specific region

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, linear-fractional-transformation

I am having a problem with a Complex Analysis question. It goes as follows:

Find a general Möbius Transformation $w=Tz$ that maps $\mathbb{A} = \{ z : |z-a|\leq R \}$ into $\mathbb{B} =  \{ w : Re(w) \leq -3\}$.

So from my knowledge, I have to set up a generic Möbius Transformation function, say
$w=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and find the appropriate $a,b,c,d$. And to do that I have to specify three points of $z$.

How would I go about choosing the points and solve the question? Because the question says find general Möbius Transformation, I am having trouble starting the question.. Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Frame challenge:  Moebius transforms are closed under composition.  Can you find a sequence of (simple) transforms to go from $\Bbb{A}$ to $\Bbb{B}$?  Perhaps, translate disk, disk -> halfplane, rotate halfplane, translate halfplane.

Comment: Consider mappings from the unit disk to the upper half-plane. The general form of a Mobius transformation has to be $w(z) = (A z + B)/(z - e^{i \phi})$. Since $w(\infty) = A$, it follows that $A$ is in the lower half-plane and that $w(0) = -e^{-i \phi} B = \overline A$ because symmetric points are mapped to symmetric points. Show that these conditions give the desired general form.